# Can't find the nuget package manager in visual studio 2017?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, nuget, visual-studio-2017

I installed package installer from *Tools*->*Extensions and Updates* .
I tried searching in the tools menu, couldn't find **install nuget package** option. 
Also if I right click on the project, there is an option **Quick Install Package**, In the box there I fill in the nuget package I want to add in my project (openBLAS in my case) and it says, *Visual studio needs to restart* .

Iam working in Visual C++ win32 console application and tried finding the nuget package manager for other projects as well.

I restarted my visual studio and even my PC too, but still couldn't find it.
Please help!

Answer (score 25, accepted):

It's not installed by default(as far as I know) you have to select It in the Visual Studio Installer manually.

First open up your Visual Studio installer (e.g., via *Tools->Get Tools and Features...*). Modify your currently installed product. You can find the *NuGet package manager* under the *Individual components* tab.

Comment: It's under "Code tools" (that dialog really needs a search feature)

Comment: Just to add a comment for edge cases, make sure you do not have the project running when you right click. If the solution is running, you won't see an option to "manage nuget packages".

Answer (score 6):

This worked for me:

**Delete `%AppData%\NuGet\Nuget.config` then
Restart Visual Studio**

(Deleting the Nuget.config forces VS to create a new config file, this can solve many different problems depending on what was broken in your config file)

Comment: That's not the problem the asker was trying to solve. He couldn't find the package manager interface in the GUI.

Comment: I actually had the exact same problem and solved it that way. Deleting the Nuget.config forces VS to create a new config file, this can solve many different problems depending on what was broken in your config file. It seems that the linked question was a little misleading here so i deleted it.

Answer (score 5):

> Can't find the nuget package manager in visual studio 2017?

As per [nuget blog](http://blog.nuget.org/):

> Starting with NuGet 4.0 in Visual Studio 2017, the NuGet Package Manager will be shipped as a part of Visual Studio, and newer versions will not be available for download from the VS extensions gallery. NuGet updates will be pulled in automatically along with other Visual Studio updates.

So **the NuGet Package Manager extension is already built-in Visual Studio 2017, do not have to install or update it.**

After install the Visual Studio 2017, you can use nuget package manager directly. Right click on the project, there is an option **Manager NuGet packages...**, In the **Browse** there filled in the openBLAS nuget package, then select the package version and install it:

[image]

Besides, you can also install the nuget package by NuGet commands directly within Visual Studio, for more detail information you can refer to the [NuGet Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/).

Comment: Sorry, but I get no such option with a fresh Visual Studio 2017 install.

Comment: Found it. I had to go to "Tools->Get Tools and Features..." and install it manually.

Answer (score 0):

My experience with VS2017 is that NuGet Package Manager was not automatically installed.  It had to be selected via the VS Installer:

[image]

Failing to select/install these on the initial install, I had to go back and add/install them later.  However, after installing, the Package Sources in the NuGet Package Manager were limited to "Microsoft Visual Studio Offline Packages" and package restore would not function correctly.  Following the suggestion of @ndreisg, I deleted the Nuget.config file.  Then upon restart of VS2017, everything worked, and I was able to restore packages to an existing solution.

Answer (score 0):

I was using Visual Studio 2017 Community and couldn't find the NuGet Pkg Manager in the Tool menu. I went to Tools->Extensions & Updates... Selected Visual Studio Update and that launched the Visual Studio Installer. After it run the update the NuGet Package Manager menu was added..